# Which of the following is a better query plan and why?

Tags: mysql

Below is EXPLAIN output of the same query. One using STRAIGHT_JOIN, the other without. Which one is a better plan?

Below are details

FIRST ONE (USING STRAIGHT_JOIN) -

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
      select_type: SIMPLE
        table: main_table
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 345
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: broker
         type: ref
possible_keys: UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID
          key: IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: category_product
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: ma.main_table.entity_id,ma.broker.entity_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: price_index
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IDX_MULTIVENDOR_WEBSITE_INDEX_PRICE_CATEGORY_ID
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 6
          ref: const,ma.main_table.entity_id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
```

SECOND ONE (WITHOUT STRAIGHT_JOIN) -

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
   select_type: SIMPLE
        table: broker
         type: ref
possible_keys: UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID  
      key: IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID
  key_len: 2
      ref: const
     rows: 1
    Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       id: 1


select_type: SIMPLE
        table: category_product
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID
          key: IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID
      key_len: 4
          ref: ma.broker.entity_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index

*************************** 3. row ***************************
       id: 1


select_type: SIMPLE
        table: main_table
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: ma.category_product.category_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where

*************************** 4. row ***************************
       id: 1


select_type: SIMPLE
        table: price_index
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IDX_MULTIVENDOR_WEBSITE_INDEX_PRICE_CATEGORY_ID
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 6
          ref: const,ma.main_table.entity_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

Comment: Please use code tags!!

Comment: Could you actually share your queries too? By the looks of this though the first will be faster, simply because it doesn't need to perform a filesort(which is relatively slow).